# Как создать Header в ListVIew?

Tags: android

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это ListView. Как создать коричневые ячейки так чтобы размер соответсвовал адаптеру ListView.

такой вариант Header сделать в адаптере, а уже программно отключить во всех других элемеьтах. Но такой вариант не подходит, потому что при пролистывании Header тоже будет пролистываться, а надо чтобы он был фиксированный

P.S. Header = "Наименование , количество, сумма"

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:src="@drawable/basket"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:id="@+id/line"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="#544234"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/line"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:divider="#544234"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: я знаю несколько вариантов, скиньте разметку я добавлю решение.

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei, вот разметка

Comment: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/10/android-fixed-header-and-footer-with-scrollable-content-layout-example.html

Comment: http://www.byteslounge.com/tutorials/android-header-and-footer-layout-example

Comment: Я имел ввиду разметку элементов в listView, чтоб удобней было выровнять. Кстати, гайды полностью решат эту задачу с полна.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

activity_main.xml

```
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/HeaderName"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/HeaderInfo"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.95"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
        android:gravity="center" />
</LinearLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollingCache="false"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
</LinearLayout>
```

item.xml

```
  <LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:paddingTop="2dp"
android:paddingBottom="2dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvDate"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.25"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:gravity="center|start" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvEvent"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:gravity="center" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

Вот набросал пример такой. Но у Listview есть свои header and footer но по мне, кастомная разметка удобней.

Comment: я восстановил вопрос и ваш ответ. В таких случаях отмечайте что-нибудь тревогой для модератора и объясняйте проблему — модераторы могут восстановить.

Comment: Буду знать, спасибо. Там кстати в заголовке ошибка теперь.

Comment: в каком из вопросов? Вы можете исправить, если знаете как.

Comment: не круто пользоваться весами :)

Answer (score 0):

Советую воспользоваться готовыми решениями для отображения таблиц. Например GridView.
Вы автоматически лишитесь проблема с подгоном ячеек к одному размеру в принципе и реализуете без всяких костылей то, что вам надо.

Единственное, вам придется чуть доделать адаптер, чтобы он умел отображать header. Для этого количество элементов увеличивается на 1, и первая строка обрабатывается индивидуально.

Comment: Есть вариант выловить размеры и использовать их при создании header, это будет круто?

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei нет, это будет костыльно в данном случае, потому что есть более нормальные решения